# Plotting chart with different colors based on value

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to display RSI as columns chart with colors of each column based on the RSI value.

I have the following code :

```
///Plot colors
DarkGreen = #26A69A
LightGreen = #B2DFDB
DarkRed = #EF5350
LightRed = #FFCDD2
DarkGrey = #BBBBBB
LightGrey = #D7D7D7

plot(RSI, title="FMG Comp", style=columns, color=(RSI<=30 ? DarkGreen : RSI>30 ? (RSI<43 ? LightGreen): RSI>=43 ? (RSI<50 ? LightGrey): RSI>=50 ? (RSI<65 ? DarkGrey): RSI>=65 ? (RSI<70 ? LightRed):RSI>=>70 ? DarkRed)), transp=0 )
```

I get the following message when compiling : "Extraneous input ')' expecting ':'."

Where is my mistake?
Thank you so much for your help! This drives me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
///Plot colors
study("Plot colors")
DarkGreen = #26A69A
LightGreen = #B2DFDB
DarkRed = #EF5350
LightRed = #FFCDD2
DarkGrey = #BBBBBB
LightGrey = #D7D7D7
RSI = rsi(close, 14)
c = color(na)
if RSI<=30
    c:=DarkGreen
if RSI>30 and RSI<43
    c:=LightGreen
if RSI>=43 and RSI<50
    c:=LightGrey
if RSI>=50 and RSI<65
    c:=DarkGrey
if RSI>=65 and RSI<70
    c:=LightRed
if RSI>=70
    c:=DarkRed
plot(RSI, title="FMG Comp", style= plot.style_columns, color=c, transp=0 )
```

Comment: Wow Andrey! Blazing fast answer! Your solution works perfectly! Thank you so much!